# Scala Implicit Search

Tags: scala, future, implicit, scala-cats

In the Scala with Cats:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}
implicit def futureFunctor
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Functor[Future] = …
```

> Whenever we summon a Functor for Future , either directly using
>   Functor.apply or indirectly via the map extension method, the compiler
>   will locate futureFunctor by implicit resolu on and recursively search
>   for an ExecutionContext at the call site. This is what the expansion
>   might look like:

```
// We write this:
Functor[Future]
// The compiler expands to this first:
Functor[Future](futureFunctor)
// And then to this:
Functor[Future](futureFunctor(executionContext))
```

Ok, I try it:

```
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, ExecutionContext}
  implicit def futureFunctor
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Functor[Future] = new Functor[Future] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => B): Future[B] =fa map f
  }

  Functor[Future].map(Future.successful(2))(_+1)
```

But get an exception:

> Error:(29, 10) could not find implicit value for parameter instance:
>   cats.Functor[scala.concurrent.Future]
>   Functor[Future].map(Future.successful(2))(_+1)

Which I would usually fix as:

```
import cats.instances.future._
```

But the fix does not help. And I must not import it, cause in the scope implicit `futureFunctor` already defined.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But get an exception:

This is not an exception, this is a compile error.

When you write `implicit def futureFunctor(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = ...` this means there should be an `ExecutionContext` in scope.
But there wasn't when you called `Functor[Future]` in `Functor[Future].map(Future.successful(2))(_+1)`.

Try

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

or

```
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

or something similar.

By the way, if you `import cats.instances.future._` and define your local `Functor[Future]` it seems the cat's one will be used.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, why I can import the first option only AFTER definition of futureFunctor. If I import it before, still a compilation error. But adding implicit to the scope in the 2nd option, works in both cases? For the 2nd option, it does not matter, where it is defined. Before or after the futureFunctor function.

Comment: @Alexandr Because if you import before then inside `futureFunctor` implicit `ExecutionContext` from `futureFunctor`'s implicit parameter and implicit `ExecutionContext` from imported `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` make ambiguity.